# Complex Analysis bounding f(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\le C|z|$ where $C$ is a positive constant. Show there exists a $D$ which is a complex constant such that $f(z)=Dz$.

I am trying to use a cauchy's estimate to show that $f''(z)=0$ but not sure how to go about this.

Comment: If you are not hell bent on using Cauchy's estimate, use the taylor expansion around zero. That should tell you which coefficients have to be 0 due to the order of growth of the function

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using Cauchy's estimate? I don't fully understand the solution attached as I don't know where the Riemann step comes from ie using g(z)= f(z)/z

Comment: Well use cauchy integral over the circle of radius $r$ and bound the integral (equivalent to using Cauchy's estimate) you should get something of the order $\dfrac{1}{r}$. Take that to infinity.

Comment: so like f''(z)= 2/r and if we r to infinity we get that f''(z)=0 and then what can we do with that exactly

Comment: This tells us derivatives of higher order are also $0$. Then use taylor expansion. There's no other way to this

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the function

$$ g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$$

for $z\neq 0$. (How do you extend it to $0$?) What can you say about this function at infinity? What do you know about such functions?

Comment: Interesting approach but requires a lot of citations